# UITextView wrapped in UIViewRepresentable doesn't show copy/paste menu

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

[image: Screen]

This is a custom textview with overrided method

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)))
}
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?